# MediaRecorder stops when screen is off

Tags: asp.net-web-api, firefox-os, web-mediarecorder

I have an application that use the media recorder with the microphone stream. Everything works fine to one exception. When I turn the display off, it stops recording and when I turn it back on it continue recording. It's as if it was pausing the stream until I unlock the phone again.

I'd like to be able to keep recording even when the display is off. I'm on firefoxOs 1.3.

Comment: I believe this is by design https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=779051

Comment: Did you try adding the permission ``"audio-channel-content": {}`` ? This lets the app play music in the background while the screen is locked but I'm not sure if it applies to microphone capture. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions

Comment: @JasonWeathersby I guess you're right. You can add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to turn the screen off using the PowerManagement API.

First, it is possible to simply turn the screen off using this code:

```
navigator.mozPower.screenEnabled = false
```

This will turn the screen off and it also means that the screen will not be responsive to screen touches. I'm not certain to know yet how we can turn the screen on yet. It could be possible to watch for physical buttons event though.

The other way would be to turn the backlight off completely, it has the same effect but the touchscreen is still responding to touch events.

```
navigator.mozPower.screenBrightness = 0
```

The only problem is that you need to have access to the setting API to disable the `screen.automatic-brightness` setting if you want to make sure that the backlight won't constantly get modified.

```
var lock = navigator.mozSettings.createLock()

var req = lock.get('screen.automatic-brightness')
req.onsuccess = function () {
  if (lock.result['screen.automatic-brightness']) {
    lock.set({'screen.automatic-brightness': false})
    navigator.mozPower.screenBrightness = 0
  }
}
```

The big problem with this solution is that the application need to add two permissions: settings and power.

Honestly, this doesn't sounds terrible for a microphone application that can modify phone wide settings, it can also have access to power management and reboot or turnoff the phone and to a factoryreset. I guess, mozilla could work on better apis to reduce the permissions needed to achieve that. Also those APIs are only available for certified apps, which means that it's not possible to push such app on any market place.